# WriteStream into Parquet file, only creates _spark_metadata folder but no parquet file

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, parquet

I am trying to write the streaming data into Parquet file using writeStream and here is how the code looks like:

```
block_sz = 1024

transactionFlattenedDf \
    .writeStream \
    .format("parquet") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/app/business_rules/") \
    .queryName("movies")\
    .option("parquet.block.size", block_sz)\
    .option("path", "/") \
    .start()\
    .awaitTermination(10)
```

I could see that the _spark_metadata folder gets created, with this input

```
{"path":"file:///part-00000-c5efe322-adbb-4699-b8b1-406f59372149-c000.snappy.parquet","size":5574,"isDir":false,"modificationTime":1596661576000,"blockReplication":1,"blockSize":33554432,"action":"add"}
```

However, I don't see the parquet file. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why docker is tagged?? are you running spark as a docker container?

Comment: @smart_coder Yes, spark is running in a docker container.